# Why pycharm can't understand var's type and show its method?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I am using IntelliJD IDEA for python programming with python plugin.
IDEA seem can't understand var's type and show its method. However it can understand java . Here is the picture :

[image]

it is good IDE auto show what requests have . But ,

[image]

IDE can't understand what type r is , and it can't give auto prompt
But I can get this feature when deal with java

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lastest version of  pycharm. With typing hint. We can have this function now:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thats because java is statically typed. Meaning thr types of the objects are known at compile time . Python in contrast is dynamically typed, so there is no type information and thus the IDE cannot know which method calls are possible.

Comment: but r = requetest.get should return var and the var must have a type, which ide can know (through analysis the request lib)?

Comment: I dont know of any ide capable of doing that since the types of the variables are decided at runtime. Before there is no typeinformation

Comment: The only way to know what type a method returns is to call it, which is problematic in an IDE. And it might return different types each time it's called, depending on the input parameters. Some IDEs, once you've run your script once, can use the last known types for future editing, however.

Comment: anyone know some usefull plugins almost do this ? when the number of source file increase , you must to see the class define then rember what it has . The Structure in idea can only show one file one time .